# Directives property in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I tried to declare my component using directives (`[]`), but it didn't work out. I then knew that in RC6 it has been deprecated. So I added the component at the declarations @ngmodule but it still not working any idea why?
edit ::
that is my module.ts ::

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {NavBarComponent} from "./Components/navbar/navbar.component";
import {AboutComponent} from "./Components/about/about.component";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ,NavBarComponent , AboutComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

that is my app.component.ts ::

```
import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
//import {AboutComponent} from "./Components/about/about.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>{{name}}</h1>`,


})
export class AppComponent  {  }
```

Now tha NavBar component has .html file ::

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Spotify</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And Navbar.component.ts ::

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl : 'navbar.component.html',
})
export class NavBarComponent  {  }
```

i am using the angular  quick start ,there is no output error but when i reload the page no change happen and the navigate bar design doesn't show

Comment: which angular version do you use?

Comment: i am using angular/cli version 1.0.1 @DmitrijKuba

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] that explains what *"it didn't work out"* means?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i edited it , sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0):

You seem to missing where your components should really be loaded, so you need to add `<router-outlet>` somewhere, that would in your case be `app.component`. If you want the navbar shown all the time, also place that tag in the `app.component`

So your app.component should look something like this:

```ts
import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavBarComponent} from "./Components/navbar/navbar.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    // Navbar always shown 
    <navbar></navbar> 

    // Your other routed components will load here 
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {  }
```

Please check the [**official docs for routing**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) for closer explanations!

Comment: Did this answer help you, or do you need further assistance? :)